# Annotation way to register listener to spring's @Retryable

Tags: java, spring-retry

How to register a listener in `spring-retry` using `@Retryable()` annotation?

```
@Bean
public RetryListener myRetryListener() {
    return new MyRetryListener();
}

@Service
public class SampleService {
   private int cnt = 1;

   @Retryable(RuntimeException.class)
   public void retryMethod(int x) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("SampleService invoked.");
      Thread.sleep(500);

      if (cnt++ < 4) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SampleService throwing exception");
      }
   }

}
```

If I create any listener bean, it automatically registers to `RetryTemplate`. So if I have multiple listeners then how can I ask particular listeners to listen to my retry-able service?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for something like below. `Retryable` annotation has listeners parameter(`spring-retry:1.2.4.RELEASE`)

```
@Retryable(value = { Exception.class }, maxAttempts = 2, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000), listeners = "networkcallRetryLogListener")
List<ServiceObj> getDataFromThirdpartyService();
```

And `networkcallRetryLogListener` tries to log in my case.

```
public class NetworkcallRetryLogListener extends RetryListenerSupport {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NetworkcallRetryLogListener.class);

@Override
public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
    LOG.warn("Retry attempt {} for retryable method {} threw exception {}", context.getRetryCount(),
            context.getAttribute("context.name"), ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(throwable));
    super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify `listeners` in `@Retryable` like this. The `listeners` attributes takes an array of strings which are bean names for implementations of `RetryListener`.

```
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 5,backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000),listeners = {"retryListener"})
public void getSomeData() {
                log.info("Get Some Date !!!!");
                throw new RuntimeException("Test Exception");
            } 


@Component
public class RetryListener extends RetryListenerSupport {

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context,
                                               RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {

        log.error("Unable to recover from  Exception");
        log.error("Error ", throwable);
        super.close(context, callback, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        log.error("Exception Occurred, Retry Count {} ", context.getRetryCount());
        super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context,
                                                 RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
        log.error("Exception Occurred, Retry Session Started ");
        return super.open(context, callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be RetryListener instead of retryListener then?

Comment: According to the JavaDoc for `@Retryable`, the value of `listeners` should be  _bean names_, not class names. I've edited the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very old pull request in the official Github repo of spring-retry, that seems to enable just what you want to do.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/pull/77